# Require Image dynamically in React Native

Tags: ios, image, react-native, local, assets

The documentation of React native (0.21) states, that it is only possible, to load pictures statically, i.e. if the file name is somehow known in advance:

> Note that in order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content

An example is given:

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />
```

Unfortunately, in my case, I do not know the file names of the pictures in advance, as they are configured in a JSON file.

Is there a way to use **local** image files within react native? I could load them via the `file://` protocol, if I knew the location of the files? Is there a constant or variable for he location of the app within the **iOS** file system?

Comment: The docs do mention that source={{uri:'local path of the file'}}.  I don't think it follows the file:/// Uri scheme. Try passing in the absolute path of the file

Comment: What is the absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use images dynamically. They're treated, however, as network images. What this means is that the packager didn't attach any image metadata (width, height).

If you've a few images, simply leverage the packager.

```
// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

The other option is to save metadata (width, height) in your JSON. You'll need to specify at least the height for network images (or dynamic images).  Given the metadata(width, height) and screen dimensions using ([React.Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html#content)), it's trivial to select appropriate height. Use [react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation) if your app needs to work in portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a hint on how to use them as "network images" what is the correct path to the images? How are they then packed into the application?